# Robotium throws NullPointerException on latest 4.2 Jelly-bean

Tags: android, robotium, android-4.2-jelly-bean

After the recent jelly-bean update I started seeing java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Searcher.searchFor(Searcher.java:107)
In my Robotium tests when it attempts to fill the user name text field and log in to the app. The same test works fine (unmodified) on 4.0.2 and on the emulator. I'm asking here to see if anyone else has run into the problem or has any workaround. I am running Robotium 3.5.1

Answer (score 2):

I just updated to the latest Robtium, 3.6 and it seems to fix the problem.